# Determining control voltage of variable gain amplifier to achieve fixed output amplitude

Tags: amplifier, control

I am wondering if there are any well known methods for determining the control voltage of a variable gain amplifier required to achieve a constant amplitude output without requiring prior knowledge of output amplitude. In other words, **I am looking for an equation that relates output amplitude to control voltage so that the amplifier produces a fixed output level for any input level**.

The VGA I plan on using is an AD600. For this VGA, the gain of the amplifier is given by Gain(dB) = 32*Vc + 20, where Vc is a control voltage between -0.625 V and 0.625 V. The only way I can think of accomplishing my goal is to use a microcontroller with and ADC and DAC to measure the output voltage of the VGA, and then adjust the DAC output to control Vc accordingly. With a microcontroller, I could keep track of previous values for output amplitude and amplifier gain, making the Vc calculation much simpler.

However, it would be a good learning exercise for me to use an equation for Vc in terms of the current output amplitude to design analog control circuits to accomplish my goal (I am studying analog circuit design as an undergrad EE). To be clear, I am not interested in designing control circuits that involve any kind of sequential digital logic, or use sample and hold circuits. If I need to use either I might as well just use the microcontroller.

Comment: sounds like you want some kind of AGC.

Comment: automatic gain control. Sounds like exactly what I need. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The AD600 is optimized for a certain type of signal applications, and might not be the best approach for yours.  What are the signal type (audio, video, RF, bandwidth, etc.) input amplitude range, and desired output amplitude?

Comment: Sonar system with frequencies from 25 to 40 hkz. Analog devices lists sonar amplifier as an example application on the AD600's datasheet. Input will be around -30 dBV re 1V and output will be around 2.6 dBV re 1V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an AGC circuit (from Electronics World, of decades ago)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB4fqf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To get minimum gain (4.7X) for low input voltages, you may need to adjust R6 downward, to reduce the D1 idling (quiescent) current; you want the reac ( the dynamic-resistance, the derivative of the diode equation) to be well above R3 (1Kohm) for low input voltages; thus you need < 10UA thru D1.

I make no promises about the distortion.